# spatial weight matrix in stata

Tags: geospatial, stata, spatial, economics

I need to set a dynamic spatial matrix of weights (the matrix changes over the years). Tell me how you can specify in the Stata code that the matrix is changing. Now my code looks like this (for a static matrix):

spatwmat using "C:\Users\User\Desktop\reg.dta", name(Ws) standardize

How do I show Stata that the matrix will be different for each year? How do I import several different matrices at all? Are there any commands to import dynamic matrices from Excel?

I searched for information on the Internet, but did not find any examples of a dynamic weight matrix. If you know where I can read about this, please write too